# A2M6020 AppleColor monitor not showing color

Tags: apple-ii, crt-monitor

When I got my Apple IIc computer, it came with an A2M6020 AppleColor 13" NTSC composite monitor. However, I have not been able to get color working on it.

I don’t know if it just has a monochrome tube in it, but I couldn’t find anything about that online. It did used to belong to a business so it could be possible. I hooked my ps1 up to it and it’s still in all green.

I just need to know if it’s a possibility that it’s got some sort of monochrome tube.

Comment: Options: (1) Color generation broken in Apple. (2) Color decoding broken in monitor. Try to find an analog TV, connect Apple //c to it and see if you get color. Conversely, try to find something that can generate a color signal your monitor can understand, connect to monitor and see if you can get color.

Comment: If something was sold as a color monitor, then equipping it with a monochrome tube would be fraud. If you can make the monitor show some image, then using a magnifier glass you will surely be able to see a pattern of red, green and blue dots or stripes. A monochrome tube OTOH will have a smooth, monochrome apperance.

Comment: The Apple IIc only produces color depending on the version: The European PAL model will only produce a monochrome signal on the composite output, NTSC versions provide a color signal. So, do you have an NTSC or PAL IIc?

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff I believe their question was more about an owner doing an aftermarket tube swap and then that not being communicated to the seller years later... like a more electrically ambitious analogue to when Adrian Black [swapped a green-phosphor Apple //c monochrome monitor CRT into a Macintosh Classic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PGqwhYGrJDI) or a weird cousin to how some CGA clones had a switch/jumper to dither output for an MDA monitor.

Comment: @ssokolow swapping from a color tube to a monochrome one would be MUCH more difficult than just exchanging a white monochrome with a green one.

Comment: What have you done to determine it isn't generating color? If you're just at text screens, that is only going to be black-and-white. If you tried booting a game or something that does graphics mode, then you should see some color. Otherwise, from the BASIC prompt (a text mode), get some text on the screen and type POKE 49232,0 (and hit return) and this will switch it into lo-res graphics mode which will certainly show SOME colors as long as there was text on the screen in the first place.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff **I** know that. I'm just saying the questioner seems to be wondering if it was within the realm of plausibility for some business with access to a skilled electrical engineer (eg. possibly a small business with an electronics hobbyist as an executive) to have done it.

Comment: The monitors text is green. I feel like if it had color it would be white.

Comment: @help According to [this repair video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1U1uRJXIUj0), the A2M6020 just takes an ordinary NTSC composite signal as input, so you could test whether it's software-generated green text or a green phosphor by plugging a known-to-be-color video source like a DVD player.

Comment: i hooked my ps1 up to the monitor and it’s still all green. i’m going to conclude that it there’s a green tube in here.

Comment: @help it would make more sense to conclude that the monitor is faulty and red and blue signals don't drive red and blue electron guns properly. It could just be a dirty adjustment trimmer.

Answer (score 4):

The Apple IIc Color monitor and the Apple IIe Color monitor both have a color disable switch in the control panel behind the flap in the front. It's the button at the right. You don't write about using that button, so maybe you are not aware about the existence / purpose of that button.

Comment: I was aware of the button. however when i press it it just shifts the letters to the right and stays the same color. I was able to find a tv with composite and hook it up to that and the color works just fine. I think the monitor just has a monochrome tube because i dont see any other explanation at this point.

Comment: Defective red, blue gun or circuitry?  I'd guess "it's broken" to be more plausible than someone putting a monochrome tube in a colour monitor.

Comment: Many monitors have pots to balance the red and blue drive level to match the get the proper shade of white. Maybe those pots went back.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher how do i get at these pots? Where are they inside the moniter?

Comment: The pots adjusting the different electron guns are typically at the "neck board". That's the PCB at the end of the picture tube.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher I found RGB Adjustments on the main board and they didnt change anything. The only one that changes anything was the Green adjustment.